# Which album's inside cover featured a policeman running after the band on a motorcycle?

Tags: vinyl, album, artwork

I saw this on a vinyl record **inside** cover in the 90's yet I can't seem to be able to remember the name/artist of this album at all which is especially shameful as I have the feeling it was a pretty famous album.

I looked at art featured on the *The Police* albums and McCartney's and Wings *Band on the Run* which seemed like good candidates but no luck.

Here's what I remember (might not be accurate):

- the scene is captured from the side (profile)
- there's a policeman with a baton on the left side, running
- on the right side there's the rear part of a motorcycle speeding away, full wheel visible
- there might be some instruments in the scene (saxophone or tuba, falling?)
- UK look-and-feel
- the art is not necessarily a photo, maybe a drawing or photo montage

Your help is most appreciated.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to recall what genre the music was, by chance?  Metal?  Punk?  Pop?  Any info like that would help narrow it down.

Comment: I would say pop-rock or progressive rock. I *saw* it during the 90's but the actual record might be older.

Comment: @JohnnyBones It's not on the cover, it's on the inside. It can very well be Chicago as they were featured on the soundtrack for "Electra Glide In Blue". Still can't find it.

Comment: I feel like I've seen this...

Comment: @ChrisSunami It's Chicago X.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer. The art is featured on the inside cover of the [Chicago X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicago_X) album.

I miss the days when albums came with great art. Here's a scan:

[image: Chicago X]